# Inconsistent Behavior of Java Unit Tests Across Environments

Tags: java, gradle, jenkins, mockito, jmockit

I have encountered an issue where several unit tests in my Java project exhibit inconsistent behavior across different environments. Specifically, some tests fail in the testing environment (as part of the Jenkins build), while the same tests pass in the local development environment. Furthermore, these tests pass again when executed in another environment, such as the QA environment. It is worth noting that the tests were written using JMockit version 1.20, Mockito version 2.8.0, and JUnit 4.12 and build are taken using gradle 4.8.

Why would tests behave differently for different environment when its same and running on same configurations

Comment: Are they really unit tests (isolated from external dependencies)?  Is the build server using a different time zone than local?  Of course, those are just a couple guesses.  Check the Jenkins test results and drill down to the failure and find the exception details, and/or check the build server logs to find the exception details.

Comment: @AndrewS Yes, build server using different timezones and some of the UTs were failing due to that. However, there were still many failing. One of the issue I've found was, in some test cases had mocked a class with $clinit and due to which other test cases throwing NullPointerException due staticInitialization skipped I believe. This fixed many of the UTs. But there are still some

Answer (score 1):

Check whether is there any order to be maintained across the Tests. Means you have to define which order the Test methods to be executed. Sometime earlier,we had faced this issue somewhere. Just check it out